# Sencha Touch 2.0.0 a view containing image a form and a comment list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i want to create a view that will contains firstly an image part where image can be come dynamically, after that a form where i can add comment to this image and finally i want to add comment list in this container related to the image.

Please give me suggestions how ican build a view like this one.

i have to create three separate views.

first image part (what kind of extend should i use that enable it to take image to show)

second form panel ( i have use extend: "Ext.form.Panel")

third comment part ( i have use extend: "Ext.dataview.List" )

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should construct your image part as **Ext.Image** (`xtype:'image'`)
- The container which contains your 3 parts should have a config like this: `layout: 'vbox'`. This will arrange your children components vertically.
- If you want the list to render properly, simply set it some configs like `scrollable: false` or in case it's scrollable, manually add a `maxWidth` config. Anyway, `scrollable: false` is more simple, let's try it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thiem, thanks for your reply. i want to be able to make a function on button tap camera of the device should open and save this image and also save this image in store as well. is it possible?

Comment: it's not possible if you don't use a middle-platform such as PhoneGap

Comment: Thiem i am very fed up from the work with sencha to read and read doc but i am failed to understand how to start my work.